# I want to clear all cart items in magento cart (In all PCs from all over world)

Tags: magento-1.9

When i run a script then clear cart items from all **PCs** which already added a cart item(s).

Comment: do you want clear cart items of both guest and registered users ? or only for guest users ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento I want delete all cart items form all types users like (logged in ,visitor,guest,etc) but logged user don't logged out when run a script for clear cart.

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question that you want to delete **cart items added in PC** , but not the **cart items added by customer**, so you can simply delete all cart items of Pc [ all over the world :) ] by deleting **Sessio**n folder present inside **Var**....

Comment: I think that will delete all user's (quest and logged) data from there added carts ?

Comment: @Jai it will delete only cart items of guest users, not the registered users.....

Comment: @Jai if you have less customer, you can delete their cart items from backend under Manage customer > click on each customers and than you can delete their cart items.....

Comment: I want delete all cart items form all types users like (logged in ,visitor,guest,etc)
@BabyinMagento if we delete session folder(var) then all logged in user automatically logged out ,so this is not a right way.

Answer (score 0):

Why shouldn't you just set all quotes to in_active by running a simple SQL Query? That should give all customers a clean new quote and you don't have to recollect totals